# How to query DynamoDB table with FilterExpression and two not indexed fields

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

With the DynamoDB table where `country` is the Primary Key and `createdAt` is a Sort Key I want to query the items where the `country` is `USA`, the city is `San Francisco` and the street is not `Market street`.  But even while there are multiple items in a table, the `query` commands returns no result. What I am doing wrong here:

```
import { DynamoDB } from 'aws-sdk';
db = new DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ apiVersion: '2012-08-10', service: new DynamoDB() })

 params = {
  TableName: 'my-table',
  IndexName: 'country-createdAt',
  KeyConditionExpression: 'country = :country',
  FilterExpression: 'street <> :street and city = :city',
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':country': 'USA',
    ':street': 'Market street',
    ':city': 'San Francisco'
  }
}

let output = await db.query(params);
```

The output is below:

```
{ Items: [], Count: 0, ScannedCount: 200 }
```

Comment: Sounds like problem with case sensitivity of values. IIRC, filter expressions are case sensitive.

Comment: It seems the case is right. Where is the case inconsistency?

Comment: If your remove `FilterExpression`, does it work? Thus, the issue is only with `FilterExpression`?

Comment: Removing the FilterExpression returns all items matching the `country`. But I want to filter  by `street` and `city` as well.

Comment: Check the case for Market street and San Francisco. Or add one filter expression at a time to see which one is failing. Now I am 100% sure it’s the case for attribute names or values that is causing the problem.